# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 error

Tags: input, radix, valueerror

So I get this error '    adj=int(input('Choose an adjective: '))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hi'' when I use this code, (The code is really simple)

```
adj=""
adj=int(input('Choose an adjective: '))
print(adj)
```

I'm new to this, so thankyou for helping!!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to take an **integer** input, whereas you are clearly inputting a string. Instead, try this:

```
adj=""
adj=input('Choose an adjective: '))
print(adj)
```